# How to add edit & delete option in odoo modal?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-9

i Open my tree view with a button but the problem is that it's open without edit option or save. I want to have a possibility to change price and qty and save it

[image]

```py
@api.multi
    def button_details(self):
        context = self.env.context.copy()
        context['view_buttons'] = True
        view_id = self.env.ref('cfg.view_order_line_form_view').id
        view = {
            'name': _('Details'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree, form',
            'res_model': 'sale.order.line',
            'views' : [(view_id,'tree')],
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'readonly': True,
            'res_id': self.id,
            'context': context
        }
        return view
```

```xml
<record id="view_order_line_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.line.forma</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Form" editable="bottom">
                <field name="product_id" />
                <field name="product_uom_qty" string="Qty" placeholder="Qty"/>
                <field name="price_unit" string="Price"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

**Updated my question** **with picutre.** This is how my tree view looks but i want to delete products or change qty

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 'flags' in python code and delete="true" in your xml code. At the top you will see a drop-down with name 'More', clicking it will give  delete option.

```
@api.multi
def button_details(self):
    context = self.env.context.copy()
    context['view_buttons'] = True
    view_id = self.env.ref('cfg.view_order_line_form_view').id
    view = {
        'name': _('Details'),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree, form',
        'res_model': 'sale.order.line',
        'views' : [(view_id,'tree')],
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
        'readonly': True,
        'res_id': self.id,
        'flags': {'sidebar': True},
        'context': context
    }
    return view


<record id="view_order_line_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.line.forma</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Form" editable="bottom" delete="true">
            <field name="product_id" />
            <field name="product_uom_qty" string="Qty" placeholder="Qty"/>
            <field name="price_unit" string="Price"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```